# How to upload box to vagrant cloud for distribution

Tags: vagrant

I've created a custom Vagrant box by installing additional software on a base box. I now want to distribute this box. I've packaged the custom box using `vagrant package`.

In following the [steps](https://vagrantcloud.com/help/boxes/create) for box creation, I am stuck at the "create provider" stage. The step asks me to name a provider and state its URL. After choosing "virtualbox" as the provider, I'm not sure what it is expecting as a URL. The `.box` file is on my local machine and I simply want to upload it to Vagrant Cloud where it may be downloaded for use by others. (image below)

[image: Please view the image below]

So my question is: Does Vagrant Cloud provide hosting space for the files or is it simply redirecting to the actual hosting site? In other words, is the URL step expecting me to provide link to a VM already uploaded to some hosting site (Git, AWS etc)?

If Vagrant Cloud does provide hosting space, can someone point me to the next step in the process? Specifically, what URL is it expecting?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you RDK - this was my exact same problem. That screen in the Vagrant Cloud UI is incredibly confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just recently run in to this very same issue and asked the same question from the support. At the time of the writing [Vagrant Cloud Beta](https://vagrantcloud.com/) does not offer box file hosting (this is expected to change very soon). Instead you have to save the box-file somewhere in the internet and provide the url to that location. Note the file can't be behind authentication.

**Update 28th May 2014**

The following note has appeared to [Vagrant Cloud Beta Help](https://vagrantcloud.com/help/cloud/hosting)-section:

> A core part of this service will be hosting of actual box files. This is being tested internally at the time of the beta launch, and will likely be a paid feature due to high bandwidth costs.

The privacy issue is still unaddressed in the [Private Boxes](https://vagrantcloud.com/help/boxes/private)-documentation.

**Update 30th May 2014**

HashiCorp has announced yesterday the end of Beta and a bunch of new features including box hosting. See their announcement for the details: [Vagrant Cloud: Organizations, Box Hosting and the end of Beta](http://www.hashicorp.com/blog/vagrant-cloud-end-of-beta.html).

Comment: I'm completely puzzled by this. If the box cannot be behind authentication, then what does it mean that Vagrant Cloud Beta provides "private boxes"? By definition the boxes are publically accessible.

Comment: @AlexDean: In Vagrant Cloud Beta the private box means that the box is not publicly visible and can't be found from the service but the owner and collaborators. However as the box file is not really behind any authentication it is available for anyone who knows the url. The best you can do at the moment is to host the box file from obfuscated url like `http://www.example.com/99be681f2de99e16c447630cce276aaff20f35b2/my-secret-ubuntu.box` and hope no-one finds it. For this reason I don't host my boxes in the Vagrant Cloud Beta, but I'll wait until they have implemented the true privacy.

Comment: Thanks @user272735 - a support contact at Vagrant Cloud confirmed what you said. They also said that true privacy aka private box file hosting is coming within days!

Comment: @AlexDean It's out now !

Answer (score 5):

From [Atlas Documentation](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/vagrant/boxes/create):

**Creating Boxes with the API**

This example uses the Boxes API to upload boxes with curl. To get started, you'll need to get an access token.

Then, prepare the upload:

```
$ curl 'https://atlas.hashicorp.com/api/v1/box/USERNAME/BOX_NAME/version/VERSION/provider/PROVIDER_NAME/upload?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

This should return something like this:

```
{
  "upload_path": "https://binstore.hashicorp.com/630e42d9-2364-2412-4121-18266770468e",
  "token": "630e42d9-2364-2412-4121-18266770468e"
}
```

Then, upload your box with the following command, with the filename in this case being foo.box:

```
$ curl -X PUT --upload-file foo.box https://binstore.hashicorp.com/630e42d9-2364-2412-4121-18266770468e
```

When the upload finishes, you can verify it worked by making this request and matching the hosted_token it returns to the previously retrieved upload token.

```
$ curl 'https://atlas.hashicorp.com/api/v1/box/USERNAME/BOX_NAME/version/VERSION_NUMBER/provider/PROVIDER_NAME?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

Your box should then be available for download.

Comment: The documentation has moved here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrant-cloud/boxes/create.html#creating-boxes-with-the-api - not sure if the old URLs are still functional, about to check out the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant Cloud does NOT offer box file hosting (at least not at this stage). Even if it will in future, I doubt that hosting will be free.

Now user can only version vagrant boxes and publish them on Vagrant Cloud using and point to self-hosted URLs.